# lazy load google maps api v3 jQuery callback

Tags: jquery, google-maps, callback, lazy-loading

I do lazy loading of the google maps api v3 javascript

The documentation says about putting as a callback parameter in the url the name of the function, which will be executed, when the script has loaded.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   var s = document.createElement("script");
   s.type = "text/javascript";
   s.src  = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=true&callback=gmap_draw";
   $("head").append(s);
 });
```

So I must define the gmap_draw() function.

When I enclose this function in the domready block, it is not visible.

Any workarounds of this issue ? (except putting the function out of the domready block)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Because the callback must be global, you could make one by accessing `window` from within the ready handler.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var s = document.createElement("script");
   s.type = "text/javascript";
   s.src  = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=true&callback=gmap_draw";
   window.gmap_draw = function(){
       alert ("Callback code here");
   };
   $("head").append(s);  
});
```

Comment: Is there no way to enter a namespaced callback name ? As you said, the above function is global, so it's more readable to put it out of the jquery block. Nice approach, thanks for sharing

Comment: If by namespaced callback do you mean defining a callback in a "myNamespace" (or similar) object?

Comment: let's suppose we have an gmapsFactory object, and I want to execute a gmapsFactory.init()

Comment: As long as `gmapsFactory` is defined in the global namespace, then that will work. The callback you would put in the URL in this case would be `gmapsFactory.init`

Answer (score 32):

Another option is to use [Google Loader](https://developers.google.com/loader/):

```
$.getScript('https://www.google.com/jsapi', function()
{
    google.load('maps', '3', { other_params: 'sensor=false', callback: function()
    {
        // Callback code here
    }});
});
```

Comment: Perfect for using inside custom classes that load the script themselves.  Thank you :)

Comment: Not sure if this is better; loading another script first (synchronously) to then load gmaps asynchronously....