# jQuery mobile: page specific javascript, hashtag pages

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, event-handling

I am creating a JQM site with multiple pages, using hashtag. e.g. index.html#a On one of the page I need to initialize a map, say index.html#map. But it occurred to me that no matter where I place the map initialization script, the script would still be executed when the index.html first load, which I want to avoid.

Although I may associate the map script with some buttons, I also want to be able to load the map when someone load index.html#map directly.

So it comes down to how can I associate JavaScript to a subpage (page with hashtag)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope all of that pages are part of a single HTML file. If I am correct you don't need to use this syntax:

```
index.html#map
```

this one will be enough:

```
#map
```

Lets say this is your HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                First Page
            </h3>
            <a href="#second" class="ui-btn-right">Next</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">

        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div> 
    <div data-role="page" id="second">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                Second Page
            </h3>
            <a href="#index" class="ui-btn-left">Back</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">

        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Then to associate a javascript to a certain page use this syntax:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
    alert('Index page');
});

$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#second', function(){       
    alert('Second page');
});
```

Here's a working jsFiddle **[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/yWTG2/)**.

Also take a look at my personal blog **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)**, it will help you to deal with jQuery Mobile page events. Or take a look at my other [**ANSWER**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468659/jquery-mobile-document-ready-vs-page-events/14469041#14469041).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found something similar by probing into a plugin $('#basic_map').live('pageshow', function()... , both works. I really appreciate your detailed answer!

Answer (score 0):

Use the callback parameter:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.src  = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=true&callback=gmap_draw";
window.gmap_draw = function(){
   alert ("Callback code here");
};
$("head").append(s);  
});
```

Make sure the callback is global.
You can find a corresponding thread here: [lazy load google maps api v3 jQuery callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102579/lazy-load-google-maps-api-v3-jquery-callback)

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){ should not be used with jQuery Mobile, it will not trigger as a page event.